# How can I identify the regional version of Painkiller Resurrection from the disc/cover art?

Tags: version-differences, painkiller-resurrection

It looks like there are no less than three different cover arts and two different disc arts for the game *Painkiller Resurrection*.

I figured that it is probably just a regional thing (eg North America release, UK release), so I tried looking up some information on what the differences are, but the closest that I could find was that one of them may be an Australian release (from a non-authoritative source).

Can anyone enlighten me as to the disparate cover- and disc-arts?

---

North American release?

[image]

European release?

[image]

Australian release?

[image]

European disc?

[image]

Australian disc?

[image]

Comment: Then I’m even more confused because that’s the one that is listed as the Australian release. Hmmm…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going by the different rating systems it appears that:

- These covers are rated by [ESRB](http://www.esrb.org/) and so are from North
  America or Canada.

[image]

Also the RP [(Rating Pending)](http://www.esrb.org/ratings/ratings_guide.jsp) on the above cover means it hasn't been given a rating yet and will be from before the game was released, so could well be promotional box art that was never used on retail boxes

[image]

- This cover is rated by [PEGI](http://www.pegi.info/) and so must be European. This particular cover is from the German release (thanks Michael Madsen) but is also used in the UK, as well as other countries I imagine.

[image]

- Also this appears to be the Australian cover:

[image]

- And this one I believe is from the Polish release:

[image]

And as for the discs, the first one is a custom cover, which looks to be just a cd shaped cutout of the second cover, and the second looks like its from the Polish release, but could also be from the other European one too

Hope this helps

Comment: The third cover is likely German, due to the [USK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USK) rating. It's worth nothing that *some* games rated 18+ by the USK are partially censored in Germany (e.g. GTA3). Details are on the Wikipedia page. I don't know if *this* game is altered for Germany, but it might be.

Comment: Brilliant answers. Very informative and helpful for future references as well. Thank you to both of you!